# sphinx documenting: .py file outside of the sphinx root

Tags: python, python-sphinx, micropython

I need some help with sphinx doc generator
My git repo looks like this:

root:

- docs (for sphinx stuff)
- code (for micropython stuff)
  The thing is that spinx not really able to use files outside of root directory.
  But no problem (I thought, after digging around in deepest stackoverflow topics)
  I created a boot_link.rst file what looks like the following. (I needed to add a title, otherwise it wont be generated.)

```
.. include:: ../../repo/boot.py

Boot file
==========
```

and my toctree in index.rst looks like this:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: source code:
   
   Boot file <boot_link.rst>
```

And now Spinx can read my boot.py file, but it is a total mess.
The boot page looks like the follow:

- First the source code, as it is(so code is there, and also every comment, basicly every caracter from the .py file, just dumped there)
- then the boot file title at the end. :D
  Can I get some help how to fix it?
  The end result should be a nice formatted page based on the comments of boot.py file. (And the rest of the files from my repo also later, for )

Comment: `include` is not defined to do what you wanted, https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include

Comment: Try the `literalinclude` directive?

Comment: To extract docstrings from Python code, you need to use the autodoc extension: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html.

Comment: literalinclude won't cut it I think, based on the description:
"Longer displays of verbatim text may be included by storing the example text in an **external file containing only plain text**. 

I tried it, and what happend is that sphinx put the whole .py file into a grey rectangle/text bubble. The code is formatted, and highlighted, but still contains the actual code also, not just the coments.

The problem with autodoc is that it tries to run my code. and even the boot.py cause all kind of errors since it is micropyton code based not desigend to run on pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, I found the solution. add this to index.rst:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: source code:
   
   autodoc
```

add this to conf.py

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../repo/'))
```

and also this:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']
```

and finally create autodoc.rst like this:

```
.. _autodoc:
 
.. contents::
 
something.py
=================
 
.. automodule:: something
  :members:
  :undoc-members:
  
  
something1.py
=================
 
.. automodule:: something1
  :members:
  :undoc-members:
  
  
something2.py
=================
 
.. automodule:: something2
  :members:
  :undoc-members:
```

I think that is it.